# Python matplotlib: How do I prevent axis autoscaling in multiple plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a beginner with both SO and Python.

With Python and matplotlib I want to create a single graph like this:

```
a |--..---/\___----\/\.../----\....|
b |---./--\_---..                  |
  |________________________________|
t  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
```

Signals (a) and (b) have the same frequency but are different in length.
The goal is to have signal (a) stretched to the width of the graph,
while signal (b) should only extend to the length comparable.

How do I set the length of the axis? This should be done automatically, as there will be a lot more signals. From my understanding, len(signal) should be used.

What is the trick to get a graph to compare signal (a) to signal (b)? Is padding zeros to signal (b) the answer?

Comment: this is the default behaviour. Just plot one after another ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the axis is indeed determined automatically, unless you specify something different (e.g. using `ax.set_xlim()`). It will always strech as to include all data that is plotted to the axes, so if one line plot is bigger than the other, it will automatically size itself to host both graphs.

That said, it's pretty straight forward to plot two graphs of different extent.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.linspace(0,16, num=100)
y1 = np.sin(x1)+3

x2 = np.linspace(1,10, num=242)
y2 = np.sin(x2)+1

plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.plot(x2,y2)

plt.show()
```

As one can see, there is no adaptation of the axes parameters in the game.